# Attempting to trigger a ASP.NET C# controller method with JavaScript inserts "undefined" as a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following date range dropdown in my ASP.NET MVC project. Not depicted in the image is a search button that a user can click once all of the fields have been entered:

[image]

The default HTML for the date range text box is the following, and a value for `value` is inserted once someone picks a date range, such as "Last 30 Days":

```
<input type="text" id="date-range-header" value="">
```

Furthermore, the HTML for the search button is the following:

```
<div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Query, new { @type = "search", @Value = Model.Query, @id = "q", @placeholder = "Type here" })
    <button type="reset" onclick="SubmitSearch()">Search</button>
</div>
```

When the search button is clicked, the `SumbitSearch()` JavaScript function is called, and then it calls another function, as shown here:

```
function SubmitSearch() {
    var query = $('#q').val();
    var dateRange = $('#date-range-header').val();

    // This alert successfully alerts "Last 30 Days"
    alert(dateRange);

    Execute(query, dateRange);
}

function Execute(query, dateRange) {
    var urlValue = "@Url.Action("MySearchMethod", "Search")" + "?query=" + encodeURIComponent(queryValue) + "&dateRange=" + encodeURIComponent(dateRange);

    // This alert successfully alerts: "/Search/MySearchMethod?query=MySearchTerm&dateRange=Last%2030%20Days"
    alert(urlValue);

    window.open(urlValue, "_self");
}
```

Then, when the `window.open` executes and inserts the URL `https://example.org/Search/MySearchMethod?query=MySearchTerm&dateRange=Last%2030%20Days` into Google Chrome's URL bar, the following C# ASP.NET method is triggered:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string query, string dateRange)
{
    // This prints: "Date Range is undefined"
    Console.WriteLine("Date Range is " + dateRange);
    ...
}
```

**My question is: why is "undefined" equal the value of "dateRange" variable in the C# method? How can I get this variable's value to be "Last 30 Days" instead?**

---

And last but not least, here is the JavaScript that controls the date range picker dropdown:

```
$("#date-range-header").daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        'All Time': [moment("1/1/2000"), moment()],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    buttonClasses: "btn",
    startDate: moment("1/1/2000"),
    endDate: moment(),
    maxDate: moment()
});

$("#date-range-sidebar").daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        'All Time': [moment("1/1/2000"), moment()],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    buttonClasses: "btn",
    startDate: moment("1/1/2000"),
    endDate: moment(),
    maxDate: moment(),
    opens: "left"
});

$("#date-range-header, #date-range-sidebar").on("apply.daterangepicker", function (e, picker) {
    if (picker.chosenLabel === "Custom Range")
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    else
        $(this).val(picker.chosenLabel);
});

$("#date-range-header, #date-range-sidebar").val("All Time");
```

And we are using this Date Range Picker: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js